# How to vectorize these two nested loops?

Tags: for-loop, vectorization, octave

Vectorize the loop without use of any for loop to get v:

```
v = zeros(10, 1)
for i = 1:10 
    for j = 1:10 
        v(i) = v(i) + A(i, j) * x(j)
    end
end
```

A is a 10x10 matrix and x a 10x1 vector

I have been trying but was not able to figure out the right answer:

```
v = A * x; 

v = Ax; 

v = x' * A; 
   
v = sum (A * x);
```

Comment: PLease do not put code in the title, it's just unreadable. And please explain what do you mean "vectorize the loop".

Comment: @PierU vectorization is an established term in Octave / MATLAB / NumPy communities. It means doing a computation across an array without an explicit loop. Check the tag [tag:vectorization].

Comment: But the other point stands. Please [edit] your post to use proper formatting and make things clear, because I can’t make heads or tails of your question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo OK, got it... That's a bit confusing, as it's called "array syntax" in Fortran, while "vectorization" in C or Fortran means something completely different...

Comment: I am new here so facing problems will try better next time @CrisLuengo

Comment: Don’t wait for next time, [edit] your post now to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

Proceed step by step, starting with the inner loop. The inner loop computes a dot product between `A(i,:)` and `x(:)`. In Octave notation it can be expressed by a simple multiplication: `v(i) = A(i,:)*x(:)`. So we are left with only one loop:

```
v = zeros(10, 1)
for i = 1:10 
    v(i) = A(i,:)*x(:)
end
```

Each iteration computes the ith element of `v` as the dot product between the ith row of `A` with `x`: we recognize here the classical matrix vector multiplication

```
v(:) = A(:,:)*x(:)
```

And since there are no more explicit indeces, all the `:` can be omitted (but as mentioned by @ChrisLuengo in the comments, it can be wise to keep it for `x`, as `x(:)` is always a column vector, even if `x` has been defined as a  "row vector" (i.e. as a 1x10 matrix))

```
v = A*x
```

Comment: `x(:)` is always a column vector, no matter what `x` is. So in the last line, I would leave `A*x(:)` unless `x` is explicitly identified as a column vector.

Comment: I didn't know! Good to know...